# Identifying which overloaded function in Eval

Tags: dwscript

I am trying to create 2 overloaded functions for a class, something along the lines of:

function Tag(Value: string): string; overload;
function Tag(Group, Element: Integer): string; overload;

In the OnEval function in Delphi, how can I tell which function is being called?  I thought I could use something like Info.Params.Count.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it, Info.FuncSym.Params.Count gives me the parameter count.